# I am getting error in dependencies while adding Admob ad in an Android app

Tags: android, dependencies, admob

I am trying to integrate admob ad in my app but I am getting some red line under one of my dependencies code.

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'**
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

while adding

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

I am getting red line under

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: and that red line will be telling you the reason too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to downgrade the appcombat version to:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

[See more here.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v7-appcompat)